# Add multiple UITextfield in UIAlertview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uialertview

I need to put 5 `UITextField` in `UIAlertView`. I use this project:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/aralertcontroller

This is my code:

```
ARAlertController *alert = [ARAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert" message:@"This is an alert." preferredStyle:ARAlertControllerStyleAlert];
ARAlertAction* defaultAction = [ARAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:ARAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(ARAlertAction * action) {}];



[alert addAction:defaultAction];
[alert presentInViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can someone help me to implement the 5 `UITextField` in my `(ARAlertController *)alert` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use something like:

```
ARAlertController *alert = [ARAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert" message:@"This is an alert." preferredStyle:ARAlertControllerStyleAlert];
ARAlertAction* defaultAction = [ARAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:ARAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(ARAlertAction * action) {}];
[alert addAction:defaultAction];

[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"First";
}];
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"second";
}];
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"third";
}];
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"fourth";
}];
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"fifth";
}];

[alert presentInViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Good luke.